# Codeigniter supports htaccess windows live server and?

Tags: php, windows, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

i am new in codeigniter, only default controller is working remaining controllers are  not working and it returns following error "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." in live server . Please give your best suggestions

Comment: It's probably has to do with your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: can you post your .htaccess file here?